# Unable to use material-ui-pickers in React js web application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement Material-ui-picker in react application .

Intergratied code from this below [link](https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/)

trying to implement complimentary design section

[image]

I used the code from the docs in seperate file and installed all the packages but getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/format'
Then i tried to import the date-fns link from node-modules folder path like this 
import DateFnsUtils from '../../../../node_modules/date-fns/form'
 then getting below error .
[image]

Does anyone successfully integrated material-ui-pickers ..
Please suggest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer the [official documentation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation)

You need install and pass utils. Firstly install utils for your library:

```
npm install date-fns @date-io/date-fns
```

Then pass them to the utils provider

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns"; // import
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function App() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9l2j10wr4?from-embed) is sandbox to play aroung :)

Answer (score 3):

You need install and pass utils. Firstly install utils for your library:

```
npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns
```

or

```
npm i @date-io/moment@1.x moment
```

or

```
npm i -s @date-io/luxon@1.x luxon
```

or

```
npm i -s @date-io/dayjs@1.x dayjs
```

("The `@date-io` library release a new version v2 that's break this module.

Please update docs and require install only version 1.X from `@date-io` in the meantime.")